# Change the rendered html for the treeview control to create a label instead of span

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, treeview, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I use a treeview control in my webform in ASP.NET and the rendered HTML is like this:

```
<td class="SingleCheckbox ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;">
   <input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1n32CheckBox" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1n32CheckBox">
   <span class="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1_0 SingleCheckbox ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1_1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1t32" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">
       Admissions and Jobs
   </span>
</td>
```

I want to replace this span with a label for = "id of checkbox" to apply styles on it.

I tried some search on jQuery to access these tags and use `.html("")` but this one replaces the text inside the span not the span itself.

I want the result to be

```
<td class="SingleCheckbox ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;">
   <input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1n32CheckBox" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1n32CheckBox">
   <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1n32CheckBox" class="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1_0 SingleCheckbox ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1_1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_TreeView1t32" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">
       Admissions and Jobs
   </label>
</td>
```

**NOTE**: I can't access these elements by id because every node in the tree has a unique id

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to create a Label. The snippet below will create a new Label element after the CheckBox with the correct "for" and hides the span

```
<script>
    $('#tableID input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        var span = $(this).next('span');
        var labelText = span.html();
        span.hide();
        $('<label for="' + $(this).prop('id') + '">' + labelText + '</label>').insertAfter($(this));
    });
</script>
```

Or create an ASP.NET adapter to generate customized html. But that is much more complex. See [Change the css styling of a checkboxlist in table ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019782/change-the-css-styling-of-a-checkboxlist-in-table-asp-net/)